# Use enforcePlatform in Kotlin multiplatform

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

How can I use `enforcePlatform` function in Kotlin multiplatform?

This works well:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("js")
}

dependencies {
    fun kotlinw(target: String): String =
        "org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-$target"
    implementation(enforcedPlatform(kotlinw("wrappers-bom:1.0.0-pre.341")))
    implementation(kotlinw("react"))
    implementation(kotlinw("react-dom"))
    implementation(kotlinw("css"))
    implementation(kotlinw("react-router-dom"))
}

kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
}
```

This reports an error `Unresolved reference: enforcedPlatform`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                fun kotlinw(target: String): String =
                    "org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-$target"
                implementation(enforcedPlatform(kotlinw("wrappers-bom:1.0.0-pre.341")))
                implementation(kotlinw("react"))
                implementation(kotlinw("react-dom"))
                implementation(kotlinw("css"))
                implementation(kotlinw("react-router-dom"))         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware that this works in a multiplatform project, but the aim is not having to specify the version for each kotlin-wrappers dependency.

```kotlin
fun kotlinw(target: String): String =
    "org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-$target-pre.341"
implementation(kotlinw("react:18.1.0"))
implementation(kotlinw("react-dom:18.1.0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use it for `JVM` targets at the moment. See [KT-40489](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40489)

Comment: It can be used in JS as well